# var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable ) not executing

Tags: jquery, datatables

```
var oTable = $('#posGridView').dataTable( {
"bPaginate": false,
"bFilter": false,
"bSort": false,
"bInfo": false,
"oLanguage": {
"sZeroRecords": "",
"sEmptyTable": ""
}

} );
```

and

```
$("#posGridView tbody").click(function(event) {
$(oTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function (){
$(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
});
$(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
});
```

The above code working fine, when I select row , it highlight. But when I Press Delete Button , selected row not deleting.

```
$('#delete').click( function() {
var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );
oTable.fnDeleteRow( anSelected[0] );
} );
```

When I put an alert(anSelected), I come to know that the statement var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable ); not executing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to take into account

- You're selecting by id on `$('#delete')`. So far I understand you have a delete button by row so you would be having several elements with the same id. This is not allowed. Add a css class to the delete button (or use an existing one) and select like this `$('#posGridView .delete')`
- If you're adding rows dynamically, you'll need to attach click event using `on` method. Otherwise new added rows won't have the click handler. The code would be somethign like this `$('#posGridView').on('click', '.delete', function(){...})`